# Allocator object type conversion

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, allocator, uses-allocator

Is there a way, having one allocator object for type T, to use the SAME object to allocate memory for any other type. Maybe some magic with static_cast or rebind can help? Because right now I only have an idea of how to use rebind to derive the allocator type for the desired object type from the original allocator, but I don't understand how to use a ready-made allocator object to create any type of object.

Comment: A particular allocator object only knows how to allocate a particular type: namely, `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::value_type`. You need to construct a new rebound allocator object capable of allocating a different type: `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::rebind_alloc<OtherType> new_alloc(original_alloc);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I had that thought because I saw a template copy constructor for the same std::allocator, but if I copy e.g. pool allocator, won't that allocate new memory? Will the pool then be shared between the two objects?

Comment: If you pool allocator has unique ownership of the pool, yes. If it shares ownership or references an existing pool, no

Comment: FYI: `template<typename U> std::allocator<T>::allocator(const std::allocator<U>&)` isn't a copy constructor. The implicit copy constructor wins overload resolution if `U` deduces to `T`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, of course, I said silly)

Comment: @user17732522 I was just wondering whether the standard requires this behavior or not. Thank you !

Comment: @IanGaspariunas Sorry, what I wrote isn't really correct. I will write it properly in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An allocator `a` of type `A` for value type `T` conforming to the standard requirements can be rebound to an allocator for type `U` via e.g.

```
std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<U> b(a);
```

(although an allocator may support only a subset of all possible types `U` and fail to instantiate with others)

Then `b` can be used to allocate and deallocate objects of type `U`. You do not need to store this allocator `b` in addition to `a` however. Each time you perform this rebind from the same value of `a` it is guaranteed that the `b` objects compare equal, meaning that one can be used to deallocate memory allocated by the other.

Note that I didn't say that correctly in a previous comment: It is not guaranteed that an allocation allocated by `a` can be deallocated by `b`. So an allocator may be using e.g. different memory resources for different types, but the memory resources cannot be embedded into the allocator and copied on allocator copy or rebind.